# How can I get "ninja_forms_submit_data" and the form itself to return an error response?

Tags: wordpress, ninja-forms

I am using the following guide:

http://developer.ninjaforms.com/codex/custom-server-side-validation/

My code (Ninja Forms version 3.3.7):

```
add_filter( 'ninja_forms_submit_data', 'my_ninja_forms_submit_data' );

function my_ninja_forms_submit_data( $form_data ) {

    $errors = [
      'form' => [
        'my-error' => __( 'An unexpected error occurred.', 'my-plugin' ),
      ]
    ];

    $response = [
        'errors' => $errors,
    ];

    echo wp_json_encode( $response );
    wp_die(); // this is required to terminate immediately and return a proper response
}
```

I can see the JSON coming through just fine, but on the front-end, ninja forms "submit" button will continue to show "Processing". Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

The code provided in Ninja forms website was not working for me either.

I found out, that you should return the response and without JSON encoding. Also I was unable to display "form error", just "field error". Not perfect, but works:

```
add_filter( 'ninja_forms_submit_data', 'my_ninja_forms_submit_data' );

function my_ninja_forms_submit_data( $form_data ) {

  $errors = [
    'fields' => [
      '5' => __( 'An unexpected error occurred.', 'my-plugin' ),
    ]
  ]; // '5' is field's id.

  $response = [
    'errors' => $errors,
  ];

  return $response;
}
```